# Rails 3 Migration not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a very simple migration which was created using the generator

```
class AddEmailToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :email, :string
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :email
  end
end
```

It works great locally

```
rake db:migrate
rails console
>> User.column_names
=> ["id", "created_at", "updated_at", "uid", "provider", "name", "role", "email"]
```

I have two versions of the app on Heroku. In one, it works fine. In the other, the column simply doesn't show up.

The output from heroku rake db:migrate looks right:

```
==  AddEmailToUsers: migrating ================================================
-- add_column(:users, :email, :string)
   -> 0.0031s
==  AddEmailToUsers: migrated (0.0032s) =======================================
```

But the column isn't there:

```
>> User.column_names
=> ["id", "created_at", "updated_at", "uid", "provider", "name", "role"]
```

(By the way, all my database changes have been via generator-created migrations; I haven't touched SQL myself nor edited any migration files.)

This is a production environment so dropping the table is not an option.

Any suggestions for things I can try?

Comment: Did you restart your console? Also, check your db on heroku for the updated table,just in case.

Comment: By "restart the console", do you mean just running heroku console again? If so, then yes, I did that.

Comment: How do I check the db on Heroku? Can I run SQL commands directly in Heroku?

Comment: not as such but you could heroku db:pull --tables users to see what's going on in it and then maybe push the table back after running the migration locally if that's possible.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Somehow it just started working. The thing that got it to work was doing a git push to Heroku without any migrations in it. Not sure why. Seems like there might be a bug in Heroku.

Comment: `heroku rake` has been deprecated. Please use `heroku run rake` instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

heroku restart

fixes the issue for me.

I think this is a bug in the heroku system. I've just emailed them asking for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run "heroku rake db:migrate" ?  This runs migrations not locally, but on Heroku.